# Unity check all objects of same tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a search game, where players must look for certain objects. Whenever the targeted object is found and has been picked up, the player wins and go to the next level. I tagged the targeted objects as "TargetObj". I successfully implemented this when there is only one object to look for. I want to modify my code to include cases where there is more than one object to look for. Here is my code :

```
public void someFunction() {
    //if we press the button of choice
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        //and we're not holding anything
        if (currentlyPickedUpObject == null) {
            //and we are looking an interactable object
            if (lookObject != null) {
                PickUpObject();
            }
        } else { //if we press the pickup button and have something, we drop it
            BreakConnection();
        }
    }
}

/* ommitted lines */

public void PickUpObject() {
    if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj").Length == 1 & lookObject.tag == "TargetObj") {
        physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();
        currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;
        pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;
        winUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    } else if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj").Length > 1) {
            
    } else {
        physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();
        currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;
        pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;
    }
}
```

I added this line, to check if there is more than one object to look for.

`else if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj").Length > 1)`

How to implement this (if the player picked up all objects of tag "TargetObj", go to next level.)?

Comment: in general you should keep the call `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj")` to a minimum and rather cache and reuse the result .. and then it sounds like you want to do a `foreach` loop ...

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by keeping it to a minimum?

Comment: Not use it if possible ;) And especially not twice in a row .. currently you use `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj")` only to check its length .. then if it is **not** `== 1` you again use `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj")` for the second case check ... rather cache it **once** and reuse the array like `var taggedObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj"); if(taggedObjects.Length == 1){ ...} else if (taggedObjects.Length > 1) { ... }`

Comment: Btw the rest of your question is pretty unclear .. what is the use case and what is supposed to happen with these multiple objects?

Comment: ok, I get what you mean here. Thank you for your explanation. But can I know the reason? I mean why should I avoid using it like this?

Comment: Because it is extremely expensive and a waste of memory and performance ;)

Comment: Ok so simply the player can pick up and drop objects, some of these objects are tagged "TargetObj" so if the player picked up an object of this tag, he wins. I want to achieve this for multiple objects. for example, if there are two objects with this tag, then if the user picked the first one and dropped it, that counts! then if he picked up the second one he wins because there are only two.

Comment: var taggedObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj");  Here is it possible to use var in c#?

Comment: course it is (see [`var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var)) .. I would even say it is often recommended as it allows you to change a method return type without having to touch all occurrences of variables using it (see also [Implicitly typed local variables (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables))

Comment: Thank you for this information.

Comment: Did you get what I'm asking about? if my explanation was clear, I will update my question because I don't want it to get closed.

Comment: When you step through your code with the unity debugger, how does it act differently from what you expect? Try putting breakpoints after each of the `if (...){` lines. Here are some questions to keep in mind: Do you need to know how many objects are left for the purposes of picking an object? Does anything need to happen if the looked Object does not match?  Is there something you can do like `if (lookObject.tag == "TargetObj") {  /* some code */ if (taggedObjects.length == 1) { /*some other code */}}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast way of doing this is to keep a counter of picked objects. Then, if the counter is equal with the number of objects with the "TargetObj" tag, then the player wins. As snippet you can have something like this:

```
Gameobject[] targetObjects; // an array where you will keep your objects with "TargetObj" tag
List<GameObject> targetObjectsList;

void Start()
{
  targetObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj");
  targetObjectsList = new List<GameObject>();
}
 .
 .
 .
 // In your method (You didn't put all your code so I will use your snippet)
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        //and we're not holding anything
        if (currentlyPickedUpObject == null)
        {
            //and we are looking an interactable object
            if (lookObject != null )
            {
                   PickUpObject();
                   
                   // I suppose that "lookObject" is the gameobject that you want to pickup. If not, replase this variable with the right gameobject.
                   if(!targetObjectsList.Contains(lookObject.gameObject))
                   {
                      targetObjectsList.Add(lookObject.gameObject);

                      if (targetObjectsList.Count == targetObjects.Length)
                      {
                          //Finish the game
                      winUI.SetActive(true);
                      Time.timeScale = 0f;
                 SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
                      Time.timeScale = 1f;
                      }
                    }
               }
            }
        }
        //if we press the pickup button and have something, we drop it
        else
        {
            BreakConnection();
        }
    }
```

Then you modify your PickUpObject method, just to pick and drop objects.

I'm sorry if I miss something. I wrote this without an editor and I didn't test the code, so please tell me if is something that I miss.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. I tested your code it is working but it has a weird issue. Currently, I have 2 objects with the tag "TargetObj". So to win I need to pick both AND one of them twice. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: I also tested for one object, and it is the same, to win I need to pick it up twice.

Comment: Hi. I edited my answer. Tell me if now are any issues.

Comment: Ok, I will test it and let you know

Comment: I tested your code. It works better than before, but it is still not working completely. I have in the current scene 3 different objects with the tag "TargetObj".  when I pick every one of them once I win. which is good. However, if I picked one of the 3 times I also win. Which is wrong. so currently the picking up of objects must be as many as the objects of this tag. This isn't what I want exactly.

Comment: so did you get what is wrong here? I mean if I picked up the same object more than once it shouldn't be counted. it should be counted just once because it is the same object.

Comment: @Okashi I understand. I edited my answer, this time I will not use counter, but a list where I save the objects. Tell me if you have other issues, if not please mark my answer as the right one. Thanks.